# Initial root password and DISPLAY?

Tags: installation

I would like to cleanly shut my system down but the response from 'shutdown -P now' is that I need to be logged in as root. I installed the 'root' command but I get an error message that 'root: cannot figure out DISPLAY, set it manually'. Since this didn't work I tried logging in as root (user name) and I realize I don't know the password. So I have two questions. One, on initial installation what does the root password become? Two, what do I do about the DISPLAY problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you don't have to know the root's password, use your own with `sudo` command.
For shutdown: `sudo shutdown -P now`, for example.

If you need a password for root, then issue:
1. `sudo su`
2. `passwd root`, and change the password.

Comment: Thank you. What is the DISPLAY problem telling me?

Comment: ROOT is a C interpreter used for data analysis in particle physics.  It was looking for a remote xclient and couldn't find one, so you would have to set the display to your machine manually (via a config file preferably) to use ROOT locally.

Comment: Sorry I thought 'root' was a command to run other commands as the admin (like su).